# How to set localtime/timezone in the most generic and distro-agnostic way?

Tags: linux, centos, docker

I've created a docker container, which is running in the wrong timezone. I personally need it to run in my timezone (Europe/Stockholm, GMT+1). Since the project is open source, other users may also wish to change that. I wish to make it easy for anyone to change this in e.g. the Dockerfile or in the docker-compose.yml.

If possible, I also wish that the solution is applicable not only on CentOS in case someone wishes to use a different distro.

***What is the most distro-agnostic approach to set the localtime/timezone in my docker container?***

---

These two approaches seem to be common but I'm not sure if they are really the best way forward for me:

#### TZ environment variable

Some Linux distros read the TZ environment variable. However, I'm noticing it doesn't work when I use the `centos:7` image.

#### /etc/localtime

You can map the container's `/etc/localtime` to `/etc/localtime` on the host in the docker-compose.yml. But when doing this, distros that use `/etc/timezone` is left at UTC and software which may be reading that will then read the wrong timezone.

Comment: `/etc/localtime` is the ultimate fallback location. I don’t understand your last paragraph on it, though. It’s a symlink in most cases. Copying the actual file to the container should produce the desired result.

Comment: @DanielB I meant that even if you take care of `/etc/localtime` it seems some software rely on `/etc/timezone`. So therefore I was wondering if the `/etc/localtime` approach was really the best one.

Comment: I guess that software needs to be fixed, then. `/etc/localtime` is available virtually everywhere, including OS X and FreeBSD.

Comment: Some distros like:

  RUN echo "Europe/Stockholm" > /etc/timezone

Others like:

  RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm /etc/localtime

Answer (score 3):

Distro-agnostic would require a script that detects which distro is being used.  This is because each distro "family" has a different way of noting timezones.  For some, adding the following to the Dockerfile might work:

RUN echo "Europe/Stockholm" > /etc/timezone

Other (e.g., Debian) require using the above and then following with another Dockerfile command like:

RUN RUN sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

Other distros (IIRC, including CentOS) would require something like:

RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockhom /etc/localtime

Making it distro-agnostic would require researching each distro's method for re-configuring the timezone.  If you look at /etc/localtime, you'll notice that it's not a text file.

Comment: And some applications ignore the OS timezone setting anyway :-7. e.g. jenkins is java based, you need to pass some java arguments to set timezone in the jenkins service/start script. So Distro-agnostic and App-agnostic would have to cover more scenarios than just /etc/localtime and /etc/timezone